# When writing a library, should you put JavaScript files generated by TypeScript in gitignore?

Tags: git, typescript, npm

I'm writing a library and I have my TypeScript files in the `src` folder. I've configured `tsc` so that it outputs JavaScript files in a `js` folder. Bundled scripts go into `dist`.

There is no apparent reason to index `js` and `dist` in the git repository since they are products of the TypeScript files in `src`. I could exclude `js` and `dist` in `.gitignore` and include them in `.npmignore` so that they end up in the final release on npm.

My tests are using the files from `js` and I run them before each release, so if the tests pass, that means the `js` and `dist` folders are OK and ready for publishing on npm.

Perhaps the downside is that you wouldn't have the compiled files when you clone the repo - you'd have to `npm install` and build them. But I think that doesn't justify having commits twice as big.

Would it be a bad practice to ignore `js` and `dist` in git?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> should you put JavaScript files generated by TypeScript in gitignore?

Yes. Definitely ignore these.

## Reason

You have it already. It is a build artifact, and build artifacts should be generally ignored in source control. In this particular case, it is also the standard practice followed by TypeScript developers.

Comment: Thought so. But I can recall seeing some libraries indexing their `.js` and `.d.ts` files and thought there was some reason behind that, holding them back.